# Ubuntu dual boot Malformed security header

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows

I am using Ubuntu a dual boot with Windows. I have opened Windows 2 years later and later when trying to boot back to Ubuntu it started giving me errors and boot is failing.

```
Malformed security header  
Failed to read header: Invalid Parameter  
Failed to load images: Invalid Parameter  
start_img() returned Invalid Parameter
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: 20.4 . I cant manually boot

Comment: There is not Ubuntu 20.4

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS (Focal Fossa)  https://releases.ubuntu.com/focal/ This is the one

Comment: @OnurYüce David is correct - but could be better said.  Ubuntu releases are in the format of YY.MM - so 20.04 indicates it was released in April 2020.  20.4 therefore is the incorrect number.  The padding with the 0 is *critical* to the release numbering.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue. The problem was Windows Boot Manager was blocking Ubuntu and even if I was booting it from BIOS it was still giving the same error. I tried to install only the Ubuntu boot manager on Windows but couldn't exactly figure out how to do it. I solved with installing Ubuntu in a new disk partition. With the new installation I was able to boot my older version of Ubuntu.